# When is it necessary to have Header unset Vary in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess

I just did a major update in my WordPress environment tonight to the latest version, and got an internal server error on the site.  I then did a full inspection to see where the issue was coming from.  I think I found the culprit...When I commented out the following line in my .htaccess file, the site came back...

```json
# SGO Unset Vary
  Header unset Vary
# SGO Unset Vary END
```

In what situations do we ever **need** `Header unset Vary` in our .htaccess file?

Comment: Any idea what the "SGO" refers to? Or what added this directive?

Comment: SGO refers to "SiteGround Optimizer", which is the plugin that added this to .htaccess. They have written an article [here](https://www.siteground.com/blog/vary-http-header) as to why they think this is necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Header unset Vary
> ```

This is probably a workaround for a supposed [bug in Apache](https://www.jeffgeerling.com/blog/2017/stripping-vary-host-header-apache-response-using-varnish) ([#58231](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58231))<sup>***1**</sup> that could prevent certain caching proxies from caching the response when the `Vary: Host` HTTP response header is set. Apache might be setting this automatically when querying the `HTTP_HOST` server variable in a mod_rewrite `RewriteCond` directive (or Apache Expression).

<sup>***1**</sup> Although this is arguably a bug in the cache, not Apache. The Apache behaviour is "by design" and a `Vary: Host` header should not prevent a cache from working since this is really the default behaviour.

However, if you are *varying* the HTTP response based on other elements of the request (such as the `Accept`, `Accept-Language` or `User-Agent` HTTP request headers) then the `Vary` HTTP response header should be set appropriately and should not simply be *unset*.

I am surprised, however, that this directive would cause an error. It implies that mod_headers is not installed - which is "unlikely". However, you can protect against this and surround the directive in an `<IfModule>` directive. For example:

```
# SGO Unset Vary
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
  Header unset Vary
</IfModule>
# SGO Unset Vary END
```

(From the indentation of the directive in your question it almost looks like this `<IfModule>` wrapper was missing?)

Now, the `Header` directive will be processed only if mod_headers is installed.

Comment: Many many thanks on this deep explanation. It's helping me understand more, and yes, the conditional component appears to have been missing.  I placed it in and all appears to be good now.

Answer (score 1):

If your site was at some point migrated from SiteGround to a different host, then you could get this problem.

The code is added to .htaccess by the SiteGround Optimizer plugin. It lacks the conditionals because SiteGround hosting always has the mod_headers module enabled.

If the site is no longer on SiteGround I recommend installing a different caching plugin, such as W3 Total Cache, since the SG Optimizer relies on SiteGround-specific server-side functionality to work properly.

After deleting SG Optimizer I would check that there are is no code remaining in .htaccess that SG Optimizer added. Definitely delete the `# SGO Unset Vary` block, however you may want to leave the `# HTTPS forced by SG-Optimizer` block if you wish to keep forcing `https://` links.